# Split Screen on booting

Tags: 12.04, gui

Sometime, when I boot into Ubuntu 12.04 I am greeted with the screen 
[image]

I have to boot again to get a normal screen. I have already tried deleting the .x* and .X* files.

Comment: This could be a driver issue. What graphics card are you using?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 7570

Comment: Also do You run multiple virtual screens? If so -- removing them, and then coniguring it again might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling your AMD drivers should do the trick:

Remove your AMD drivers first:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Now install ATI Catalyst v#:

```
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run
chmod +x amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run
```

Finish the installation:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Then reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

I hope this solves your problem